# Matlab - Constructor doesn't initliaize member values

Tags: matlab, variables, interface, constructor

Dear lovely community,

I already looked in Google and in the forum and also found some interesting posts. But in the end I still didn't get it worked. So, I am going to post the question here. I know in Matlab are already get/ Set methods implemented, but I am using objects and therefore I didn't understand where to implement them.

Overall Structure:

```
+Measurement\MeasurerIF
+Measurement\MeasurerComponent
```

In my Interface I declare my functions I want to implement and this Interface is furthermore abstract. It looks like this:

```
classdef MeasuererIF < handle

methods (Abstract=true)

    getStatus(cObj) ;
    setStatus(cObj,iStatus) ;
    getInfo(cObj) ;
    setInfo(cObj,sInfo) ;
end
```

end

Then I created the other class MeasurerComponent in which I implemented the methods and also the constructor:

```
classdef MeasurerComponent < PerformanceMeasurement.MeasuererIF
%% MeasurerComponent: Evaluates which model is used and contains them as childs.
%   Detailed explanation goes here

properties (Access=protected)
    miStatus;
    msInfo;
    mcData;
end

methods 

    %constructor
    function cObj = PerformanceMeasurement.MeasurerComponent ;

        cObj.miStatus = -1 ;
        cObj.msInfo = 'Import' ;
        cObj.mcData = [] ;
    end


    %Status
    function setStatus(cObj,iStatus)

        cObj.miStatus = iStatus;
    end

    function iStatus = getStatus(cObj)

        iStatus = cObj.miStatus;
    end

    %Info
    function setInfo(cObj,sInfo)

        cObj.msInfo = sInfo;
    end

    function sInfo = getInfo(cObj)

        sInfo = cObj.msInfo ;
    end

end
```

end

Earlier I just used the `get`Methods and recently added the `set`Methods and now it doesn't work anymore. The Problem is that when I create an object

```
obj = Measurement.MeasurerComponent
```

the programm doesn't initialize the values anymore.

```
For a = obj.getInfo;
```

I receive just `[]`

Does someone has an idea why it doesn't get initialized anymore? After I received a tip I changed the initialization process to the constructor due to the handle class.

I am really thankful and glad about each hint and tip!
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor should be defined by `function cObj = MeasurerComponent`, without the `PerformanceMeasurement` prefix. This is just the way that packages are defined and used in Matlab - you add the prefix if using the class from outside the package, but not within the package (explained here: "Note that definitions do not use the package prefix" - 
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html?refresh=true).

Also, you have a typo - your abstract parent class file is called `+Measurement\MeasurerIF` but in the definition you spell it `MeasuererIF`. It doesn't matter which one it is called, but the name of the class does have to match the filename!

If I correct both of these issues, then your code becomes

`+Measurement\MeasurerIF`

```
classdef MeasurerIF < handle

    methods (Abstract=true)

        getStatus(cObj)
        setStatus(cObj,iStatus)
        getInfo(cObj)
        setInfo(cObj,sInfo)
    end
end
```

`+Measurement\MeasurerIF`

```
classdef MeasurerComponent < Measurement.MeasurerIF
    %% MeasurerComponent: Evaluates which model is used and contains them 
    %% as childs.

        properties (Access=protected)
        miStatus
        msInfo
        mcData
    end

    methods

        %constructor
        function cObj = MeasurerComponent

            cObj.miStatus = -1 ;
            cObj.msInfo = 'Import' ;
            cObj.mcData = [] ;
        end


        %Status
        function setStatus(cObj,iStatus)

            cObj.miStatus = iStatus;
        end

        function iStatus = getStatus(cObj)

            iStatus = cObj.miStatus;
        end

        %Info
        function setInfo(cObj,sInfo)

            cObj.msInfo = sInfo;
        end

        function sInfo = getInfo(cObj)

            sInfo = cObj.msInfo ;
        end

    end
end
```

and if I type the following:

```
obj = Measurement.MeasurerComponent;
obj.getInfo
```

then I get back

```
ans =

Import
```

which is what I expect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't knew that the prefix is not necessary. This helps me out a lot and the link you provided is really helpful. Can't test it right now, but during the day I will give you more precise feedback. But surely it will work out this way. So thanks a lot that you spent your time on a Sunday for my problem! You are great!

The problem with the typo was, that the computer I wrote the entry is not the one where my matlab is installed and so I wrote it down from memory. Unfortunately I made a mistake by writing it. In the files was no typo.

Comment: Hello Tom! I was just able to implement your suggestions and all is working pretty fine! I would love to upvote you, but my reputation is too small so in text form: Thank You!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help, and good luck with your Matlab programming!